# How to insert data into php multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This one should be straight forward, but I am having issues as I have not worked with arrays that much.

So I am try to insert data into a 3 dimensional array, this is the structure of my 3 dimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => name
                    [by] => by
                    [imgUrl] => imgUrl
                    [linkUrl] => linkUrl
                    [date] => date
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => name
                    [by] => by
                    [imgUrl] => imgUrl
                    [linkUrl] => linkUrl
                    [date] => date
                )

        )

)
```

I am trying to push the existing array downwards, the existing [0] becomes [1], ect. While the new [0] will be the posted data from a form.

I have tried `array_push`, `array_splice`, `array_merge`, but all to no avail.

Comment: Rizier123, I have tried:                                                                                                             array_push($json[data], $updatejson);

Comment: deleted the other comments, now I see what you want.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly...

[here's a fiddle.](https://3v4l.org/bbp5P)

```
$multi = array(
    "data" =>array(
        array(
            'something1' => 'something else',
            'something0' => 'something else',
            'something345' => 'something else'  
        ),
         array(
            'something1' => 'something else',
            'something0' => 'something else',
            'something345' => 'something else'  
        ),
    )    
);

$new = array(
    'something1' => 'something else',
    'something0' => 'something else',
    'something345' => 'something else'  
);

array_push($multi['data'], $new);

print_r($multi);
```

Comment: That's what OP already did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521356/how-to-insert-data-into-php-multi-dimensional-array#comment56784327_34521356

Comment: doubt it. if he did he wouldn't be posting. don't believe everything op tell you.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [array_unshift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) function:

```
array_unshift($arr["data"], $new);
```

Test script:

```
$arr = Array(
    "data" => Array(
            Array(
                    "name" => "name",
                    "by" => "by",
                    "imgUrl" => "imgUrl",
                    "linkUrl" => "linkUrl",
                    "date" => "date"
                )
            ,Array(
                    "name" => "lastname",
                    "by" => "by",
                    "imgUrl" => "imgUrl",
                    "linkUrl" => "linkUrl",
                    "date" => "date"
                )
        )
);

$new = Array(
        "name" => "newname",
        "by" => "newby",
        "imgUrl" => "newimgUrl",
        "linkUrl" => "newlinkUrl",
        "date" => "newdate"
    );

array_unshift($arr["data"], $new);
print_r ($arr);
```

Output shows that new element pushes the other elements down:

```
array(1) {
  ["data"]=> array(3) {
    [0]=>  array(5) {
      ["name"]=> string(7) "newname"
      ["by"]=> string(5) "newby"
      ["imgUrl"]=> string(9) "newimgUrl"
      ["linkUrl"]=> string(10) "newlinkUrl"
      ["date"]=> string(7) "newdate"
    }
    [1]=> array(5) {
      ["name"]=> string(4) "name"
      ["by"]=> string(2) "by"
      ["imgUrl"]=> string(6) "imgUrl"
      ["linkUrl"]=> string(7) "linkUrl"
      ["date"]=> string(4) "date"
    }
    [2]=> array(5) {
      ["name"]=> string(9) "firstname"
      ["by"]=> string(2) "by"
      ["imgUrl"]=> string(6) "imgUrl"
      ["linkUrl"]=> string(7) "linkUrl"
      ["date"]=> string(4) "date"
    }
  }
}
```